# How to assign a double pointer to arrays? C/C++

Tags: c++, c, arrays, pointers

I would like to create a two-dimensional array by merging two one dimensional arrays by using a double pointer and here is my code (also how would the same thing look like in C++?):

```
#include "stdio.h"
int main()
{
  int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
  int b[]={6,7,8,9,0};
  int **p;
  p=a;
  (++p)=b;
  printf("%d",p[0][2]);
  return 0;
}
```

Compiled it displays an error:

```
kek.c:7:4: warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
p=a;
kek.c:8:8: error: lvalue required as left operand of assignment
(++p)=b;
```

Comment: How about using [vectors](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/)

Comment: I'm not familiar with vectors. Where can I learn about them?

Comment: You simply cannot do what you want. a is not of type int**, for example. Walk through this with a debugger to see what's happening.

Comment: You can learn about vectors here: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/vector-in-cpp-stl/

Comment: Basically, you'd have to declare another array of pointers to int and store array addresses there. But I strongly recommend using `std::vector` in C++, as mentioned above.

Comment: Please decide first if you want to use C or C++. Those are very different languages!

Comment: @RobertHarvey I wouldn't trust anything from that site. They have all sorts of crap, such as [calling `__gcd` a built-in function in the STL](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/stdgcd-c-inbuilt-function-finding-gcd/) and loads of bad practices. For example, the first two lines of some of the code examples in the page you linked to are `#include <bits/stdc++.h>` and `using namespace std;`. It's better to learn this from a good book or a good reference site like cppreference.com

Comment: I'm more about the C one @Superlokkus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is probably this:

```
int a[]={1,2,3,4,5};
int b[]={6,7,8,9,0};
int **p = new int*[2 * sizeof(int*)];
*p = a;
*(p + 1) = b;
...
delete[] p;
```

In your code `p` is unitialized, and referencing an unallocated pointer is a serious problem (SEGMENTATION_FAULT most of the time). Important: `delete[] p` to deallocate dynamic memory allocation, whereas you do not need to deallocate `a` and `b` because they are on the stack.

Note that `int a[]` is the same as `int* a`, for this reason you can assign to `*p` a memory address.

---

**Edit**

@Bob__ is right. You do not really need dynamic allocation. a simple direct list
initialization (or copy list like in his example) is enough.

```
int *(p[2]){a, b};
```

Comment: Please note that, in the posted use case, there's no need for dynamic allocation: https://wandbox.org/permlink/cL0Yp7zeSSSxZsBm

Comment: Okay, thanks! But could you write me some code that would do what I just drew here?
https://i.imgur.com/9vljEt5.jpg